# Pick Up Sticks / Intelligent AI / Python

Tags: python

**BACKGROUND INFO, DON'T HAVE TO READ IF YOU'D JUST LIKE TO VIEW THE PROBLEM WITH CODE BELOW:**

I hope everyone is familiar with the game of sticks or "nim." If not, you set a starting amount of sticks (between 10 and 50) and draw (1-3 sticks) until there aren't any sticks left, declaring the one who pulled the last stick the loser. In my programming class we've also included the option of playing against the AI. But, the AI is no longer a dummy who randomly picks a number 1-3. Now he learns from each of his turns.

**Implementation**:

- The AI has a bucket for each of the number of sticks left. There is a bucket for 1 stick 
  left, 2 sticks, 3 sticks, etc.
- At the beginning of the game each bucket has 3 balls in it. Each marked with the choice 
  1, 2 or 3. These represent the AI’s choice of picking up 1, 2 or 3 sticks.
- During the AI’s turn, it takes a random ball from the bucket representing the number of 
  sticks left. It reads the ball and removes that number of sticks from the pile. It then 
  places the ball in front of the bucket.
- If the AI wins the game, then it goes through all of its choices and puts two balls back for 
  the chosen number for each choice it made. Increasing its chances of choosing that ball 
  the next time it’s faced with a choice with the given number of sticks.
- If the AI loses, then it throws the ball away next to the buckets. However, if the chosen 
  ball is the last choice then it puts it back into the bucket. The bucket must contain at 
  least one of each number. So if the user chose a ball that had a number of sticks to 
  pick from a bucket, and it was the last ball of that choice, then if the AI loses, it must put 
  that ball back. It can never remove any of the choices completely from the buckets.
- As more games are played the AI will reinforce good choices with extra balls for winning 
  sticks picked up."

Here's the code I'm working with right now.

```
choice=random.randint(1,maxchoice) #computer picks a random number
bucketnum=sticks #bucket to take ball from
pullnum=choice #ball to take 
for i in bucket:
    for bucket[bucketnum] in i:
        bucketnum.pop(pullnum)
    print(bucket[bucketnum])
```

The bucket that I'd be taking the ball out of would essentially be the number of sticks left, I'm just having trouble finding a specific bucket in the bucket list and taking out the ball. Right now I get an error message saying that bucketnum.pop(pullnum) - 'int' object has no attribute to 'pop'? This is the bucket code (lists within a list):

```
bucket=[]
for j in range(51):
    bucket.append([1,2,3])
```

I may be totally confusing but if anybody has any advice or even questions for clarification, please do reply. Thanks all.

**EDIT:**
Here's some more code, sorry, stupid of me to refrain from adding the definitions of variables, etc.

```
            if option==2:
            sticks=""
            while True:
                    try:
                        sticks=int(input("Enter the number of sticks to begin with: "))
                        if sticks>=10 and sticks<=50:
                            print("Alright, there are",sticks,"sticks in the pile.")
                            break
                        else:
                            print("You mut enter an integer. (10-50)")
                    except ValueError:
                        print("You must enter an integer.")
            player1=True
            while sticks>0:
                maxchoice=min(3,sticks)
                choice=-1
                countbucket=0
                if player1:
                    while choice<1 or choice>maxchoice:                           
                        try:
                            choice=int(input("Player 1, how many sticks would you like to take? (1-3): "))
                            if choice>=1 and choice<=3:
                                sticks-=choice
                                print("There are",sticks,"sticks remaining.")
                            else:
                                print("You must enter an integer from 1-3.")
                        except ValueError:
                            print("You must enter an integer.")
                    player1=not player1
                else:
                    choice=random.randint(1,maxchoice)
                    bucketnum=sticks
                    pullnum=choice
                    for i in bucket:
                        for bucket[bucketnum] in i:
                            bucketnum.pop(pullnum)
                        print(bucket[bucketnum])
                    sticks-=1
                    print("Computer drew",choice,"stick(s). There are",sticks,"sticks remaining.")
                    player1=not player1
            if player1==False:
                print("Player 1 took the last stick.\nComputer wins!")
            else:
                print("Player 1 wins!")
```

This is option 2 in my program, as option 1 is Player 1 vs. Player 2. Obviously I haven't gotten very far with the implementation of the AI intelligence, it's a bit tricky.

-----> Fred S., I'm just getting started and having issues getting the mental wheel spinning. What's excerpted isn't all of the code. I'm not asking how to complete the assignment at this point, though tips on executing this new intelligent AI code would be helpful, but in this case it's more a focus on figuring out list indexing.

Comment: Can you include a little more code? We need to be able to see where and how you're defining sticks and choice.

Comment: as the error suggested, please check `bucketnum`, is this an integer? that's why it has no attribute of `pop`

Comment: Well your description is very clear about how you want it to work, but your code does not even come close to matching the description.  There's so many problems, it's hard to know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're assigning the variable in the inner for loop to 'bucket[bucketnum]'.  Which surprises me that that's not a syntax error, but I don't think that's what you're trying to actually do.

If you're dealing with a nested list, and the position in the list corresponds to the number of sticks left, then you want to index that list by the position in order to get that bucket, instead of iterating over that list to find it.

If you think of it like this:

```
buckets = [[1,2,3], ..., ..., ...]
```

Then the bucketnum is the position of the bucket in the list of buckets.  So, in your case, if you want to grab the bucket for '26' sticks, you would access it by indexing buckets by that number.

```
buckets[25] # 25 since you're counting from 0+
```

At this point, you have the bucket in question, and can pop the choice from it.

```
bucket = buckets[25]
bucket.pop(pullnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define option
You didn't import the random library.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30836085)